Can White still castle? #3
Here is a new (retrograde?) chess puzzle, directly inspired by an exchange with Laska that came up in this recent puzzle.
In contrast to my usual chess puzzles, this one is relatively light on the retrograde analysis and also should be quite approachable - so if you're new to the genre, please feel free to have a go at it:
Can you reach this position in such a way that White can still castle in the remainder of the game?


(9+8), FEN : 8/4p1pB/4P1P1/2p5/2Pp4/3Pp2p/4P1kP/b3K2R

Please provide your reasoning in your answer. Have fun! :)

Nice - I spotted the trick though. Btw, I thought for a minute that #3 meant "mate in 3" but I guess that it's just a counter for your problems with such a stipulation

@Laska Ah I see how that title might be confusing :) What I found curious about this position is that under the more formal convention of the Codex, the answer to "Can White castle?" would still be the same as in the 'casual' interpretation, but for a different reason ... (Assuming, of course, that I understood the convention correctly)

ooh, the trick is so nice! It's not about reaching the position that's tricky, but to actually execute the castling move.

With a pure retro stipulation, the conventions by default don't trigger. The castling/e.p. conventions were designed over a century ago to resolve ambiguities in forward play problems: "White to play and mate in 3", "Black to play and helpmate in 2" etc.  They don't establish abstract rights, they just indicate, if there's doubt, whether a certain move is playable. Castling yes, en passant no. And after a castling is played, then the remaining rights must be such that the move was indeed legal


 YES

Very important is that

 The last move played must be c2-c4.
 That way, the game can continue with ...dc3 en passant, with later, for instance, ...c2, ...c1N, ...Nxe2, ...Nc3, ...Kf3, freeing the White king and rook.
 Another solution would be to promote the wPd3 to a rook or knight, capture h3 and let the bK escape, but the point is that without the en passant capture there is no way to un-encage the kings without losing castle rights.

Until now

 White was only moving their bishop aimlessly, but now they can castle.

Meanwhile the retrogade analysis

 brings no particular challenge: we can easily reach this position wihtout moving the wKe1 nor the wRh1.

Proof game :

  1. d3 a5 2. Be3 a4 3. f4 d5 4. f5 Kd7 5. g4 h5 6. Bg2 Kd6 7. Be4 Ke5 8. Qd2 Be6
  9. fxe6 f5 10. Nc3 f4 11. g5 Rh7 12. Bxh7 Nf6 13. g6 Kf5 14. Nf3 Kg4 15. Ne5+ Kh3 16. Nd7 fxe3 17. Nxf8 Kg2 18. Qd1 a3 19. Nd7 axb2 20. Qb1 bxa1=B 21. Qxb7 Rxa2 22. Qxb8 Nxd7 23. Nxa2 Nxb8 24. Nb4 c5 25. Bg8 Nd7 26. Nc6 Nf6 27. Na5 Nh7
  28. Bxh7 Bb2 29. Nb3 Qg8 30. Na1 Bd4 31. Bxg8 Bxa1 32. Bh7 d4 33. Bg8 h4 34. Bh7 h3 35. c4


  We have reached OP's diagram. From there:
  35...dxc3ep 36. Bg8 c2 37. Bh7 c1=N 38. Bg8 Nxe2 39. Bf7 Nc3 40. Bg8 Kf3 41. O-O
 achieves the task !


Oh wow, that was very fast! :) Nicely done!

I didn't immediately see why this wouldn't work: use white's bishop to take h3, thus allowing h2 to advance in turn freeing black's king to move out of the way (all the while black's bishop would be moving aimlessly to avoid stalemate).  But I guess the problem with that is that there's no way to avoid the white bishop giving checkmate from c6 while making its way to h3, right?

But what about using the existing black bishop to take h2?  Edit: Oh, I guess there's no way to avoid a check from b4 or a5 or c3 forcing the white king to move on that path.

@DanielSchepler Well spotted! In some sense, these two false hopes were the "intended" first thoughts that I expected a solver would try, before finding the correct, sneakier option :)

White cannot castle in this position; to do so would place the white king in check at g1 (from the black king), and additionally, the white king as part of the castling move would have to cross a square (f1) that is under attack (from the black king).
(see FIDE rules, 3.8.2.2 (3))
I see no way to "retreat" the black king to enable white to castle in the future, assuming that none of the other restrictions on castling have been violated.

The question is asking if White could have the option to castle at some point after this position.

@DanielMathias - That's not how the question appears to be worded to me.

@DanielMathias Interpretation is correct though, the question asks about the entire remainder of the game, not just the current position! :)

It is worded "in the remainder of the game", not "on the next move"...
